# AirPort Express Base Station "Guest" network does not allow logons. (spinning wheel)

Tags: airport, guest-account

I have set up an [AirPort Express Base Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort_Express#Models) ([June 2012 model](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP651), the current one). For setup, I used a Yosemite MacBook Pro over Ethernet. The AirPort Express has an Ethernet running from the WAN port to a [CLEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearwire) modem (a [WiMAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX) service) in "Bridged" mode.

Both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks work well, devices connect with password and surf the web.

The third network, the *Guest* network, does not let any client connect. I've tried both the MacBook Pro, an iPhone 5, and a MacBook Air repeatedly, power cycled, and so forth. When they attempt to join the **password is accepted but the spinning wheel never stops** and the computer/device never finishes joining the network. We can switch back to either the 2.4 or 5 network instantly with no problems.

Any suggestions? Might [Bridged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)) mode be a problem with a Guest account?

Comment: It seems to be a real problem with DHCP on guest wifi network.
I'm using a DHCP server from outside (not Airport DHCP)
DHCP works fine on primary Wifi Network.
Buty DHCP does not work fine on Guest Wifi Network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the bridge mode:

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204590):

> The DHCP and NAT option in AirPort Utility application > Network tab > Router Mode (default mode) must be selected on your primary base station (…)

If you had more than one Airport, all secondary stations must have Bridge mode on, given there is one Airport or Time Capsule working as the primary station.